# Azure Firewall: Most common Azure Firewall Policy Rule Collection Rules

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I am asked to configure the Azure Firewall Policy Rule collection with most commonly used Network Rules and Application Rules.

I have gathered the following details where in I have captured the most commonly used Network Rules and Application Rules. However I am not sure if I am missing anything that is considered as the most common rule?

```
resource "azurerm_firewall_policy_rule_collection_group" "fwpolrcg" {
  name               = "fwpolicy-rcg"
  firewall_policy_id = azurerm_firewall_policy.fwpol.id
  priority           = 100

  network_rule_collection {
    name     = "network_rule_collection1"
    priority = 100
    action   = "Allow"

    rule {
      name                  = "AllowHubToSpokeRDP"
      protocols             = ["TCP","UDP"]
      source_addresses      = var.hub_firewall_ip_range
      destination_addresses = var.spoke_firewall_ip_range
      destination_ports     = ["3389"]
    }

    rule {
      name                  = "AllowSpokeToHubRDP"
      protocols             = ["TCP","UDP"]
      source_addresses      = var.spoke_firewall_ip_range
      destination_addresses = var.hub_firewall_ip_range
      destination_ports     = ["3389"]
    }

    rule {
      name                  = "AllowHubToSpokeHTTPS"
      protocols             = ["TCP"]
      source_addresses      = var.hub_firewall_ip_range
      destination_addresses = var.spoke_firewall_ip_range
      destination_ports     = ["443"]
    } 

    rule {
      name                  = "AllowSpokeToHubHTTPS"
      protocols             = ["TCP"]
      source_addresses      = var.spoke_firewall_ip_range
      destination_addresses = var.hub_firewall_ip_range
      destination_ports     = ["443"]
    }

    rule {
      name                  = "AllowHubToSpokeDNS"
      protocols             = ["TCP","UDP"]
      source_addresses      = var.hub_firewall_ip_range
      destination_addresses = var.spoke_firewall_ip_range
      destination_ports     = ["53"]
    }

    rule {
      name                  = "AllowSpokeToHubDNS"
      protocols             = ["TCP","UDP"]
      source_addresses      = var.spoke_firewall_ip_range
      destination_addresses = var.hub_firewall_ip_range
      destination_ports     = ["53"]
    }
  }

  application_rule_collection {
    name     = "application_rule_collection1"
    priority = 100
    action   = "Allow"

  rule {
    name = "Windows Update"
    source_addresses = ["*"]
    fqdn_tags = [
      "AppServiceEnvironment", 
      "AzureBackup", 
      "AzureKubernetesService", 
      "HDInsight", 
      "MicrosoftActiveProtectionService", 
      "WindowsDiagnostics", 
      "WindowsUpdate",
      "WindowsVirtualDesktop"]
  }    

    rule {
      name             = "AllowMicrosoftFqdns"
      source_addresses = ["*"]

      destination_fqdns = [
        "*.cdn.mscr.io",
        "mcr.microsoft.com",
        "*.data.mcr.microsoft.com",
        "management.azure.com",
        "login.microsoftonline.com",
        "acs-mirror.azureedge.net",
        "dc.services.visualstudio.com",
        "*.opinsights.azure.com",
        "*.oms.opinsights.azure.com",
        "*.microsoftonline.com",
        "*.monitoring.azure.com",
      ]

      protocols {
        port = "80"
        type = "Http"
      }

      protocols {
        port = "443"
        type = "Https"
      }
    }

    rule {
      name             = "AllowFqdnsForOsUpdates"
      source_addresses = ["*"]

      destination_fqdns = [
        "download.opensuse.org",
        "security.ubuntu.com",
        "ntp.ubuntu.com",
        "packages.microsoft.com",
        "snapcraft.io"
      ]

      protocols {
        port = "80"
        type = "Http"
      }

      protocols {
        port = "443"
        type = "Https"
      }
    }
    
    rule {
      name             = "AllowImagesFqdns"
      source_addresses = ["*"]

      destination_fqdns = [
        "auth.docker.io",
        "registry-1.docker.io",
        "production.cloudflare.docker.com"
      ]

      protocols {
        port = "80"
        type = "Http"
      }

      protocols {
        port = "443"
        type = "Https"
      }
    }

    rule {
      name             = "AllowAzure"
      source_addresses = ["*"]

      destination_fqdns = [
        "*.azure.*"
      ]

      protocols {
        port = "80"
        type = "Http"
      }

      protocols {
        port = "443"
        type = "Https"
      }
    }
  }

  rule {
    name             = "AllowBing"
    source_addresses = ["*"]

    destination_fqdns = [
      "*.bing.com"
    ]

    protocols {
      port = "80"
      type = "Http"
    }

    protocols {
      port = "443"
      type = "Https"
    }
  }

  rule {
    name             = "AllowGoogle"
    source_addresses = ["*"]

    destination_fqdns = [
      "*.google.com"
    ]

    protocols {
      port = "80"
      type = "Http"
    }

    protocols {
      port = "443"
      type = "Https"
    }
  }  

  depends_on                = [azurerm_firewall_policy.fwpol]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to create Azure Firewall Policy Rule Collection Rules using Terraform:**

> Note: Make sure that define all rules in collection section inorder to block or deny the action.

See the [document](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/firewall_policy_rule_collection_group) to create **Azure Firewall Collection Group** using Terraform.

**Terraform code:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "Thejesh" {
  name     = "Thejesh-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_firewall_policy" "example" {
  name                = "example-fwpolicy"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.Thejesh.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.Thejesh.location
}

resource "azurerm_firewall_policy_rule_collection_group" "example" {
  name               = "example-fwpolicy-rcg"
  firewall_policy_id = azurerm_firewall_policy.example.id
  priority           = 500
  application_rule_collection {
    name     = "app_rule_collection1"
    priority = 500
    action   = "Deny"
    rule {
      name = "app_rule_collection1_rule1"
      protocols {
        type = "Http"
        port = 80
      }
      protocols {
        type = "Https"
        port = 443
      }
      source_addresses  = ["10.0.0.1"]
      destination_fqdns = ["*.microsoft.com","*.cdn.mscr.io",
        "mcr.microsoft.com",
        "*.data.mcr.microsoft.com",
        "management.azure.com",
        "login.microsoftonline.com",
        "acs-mirror.azureedge.net",
        "dc.services.visualstudio.com",
        "*.opinsights.azure.com",
        "*.oms.opinsights.azure.com",
        "*.microsoftonline.com",
        "*.monitoring.azure.com",]
    }
  }

  network_rule_collection {
    name     = "network_rule_collection1"
    priority = 400
    action   = "Deny"
    rule {
      name                  = "network_rule_collection1_rule1"
      protocols             = ["TCP", "UDP"]
      source_addresses      = ["10.0.0.1"]
      destination_addresses = ["192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.2"]
      destination_ports     = ["80", "1000-2000"]
    }
  }

  nat_rule_collection {
    name     = "nat_rule_collection1"
    priority = 300
    action   = "Dnat"
    rule {
      name                = "nat_rule_collection1_rule1"
      protocols           = ["TCP", "UDP"]
      source_addresses    = ["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2"]
      destination_address = "192.168.1.1"
      destination_ports   = ["80"]
      translated_address  = "192.168.0.1"
      translated_port     = "8080"
    }
  }
}
```

**Terraform plan:**

[image]

**Terraform Apply**

[image]

Once ran the code resources created with **Azure Firewall Policy**.

[image]

**Rule collection inside Azure Firewall.**

[image]

**Application Rules in Azure Firewall:**

[image]